# How to install kubuntu on Lenovo thinkpad e555

Tags: grub2, partitioning, kubuntu, lenovo, thinkpad

I have been trying to install Kubuntu 15.04 on Lenovo ThinkPad E555. I have created `/`, `/home` and `/boot` partition but as soon as I install it, it doesn't show up on boot screen (it only shows Windows but I already deleted all Windows partition). Secure boot is on and USB has UEFI setup of Kubuntu. I have also tried to install it without `/boot` partition (install grub on `/sda` partition) but with no luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please run the [Boot Info Script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) (available in the `boot-info-script` package) from an Ubuntu live disk. That will generate a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Post that file to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com/) and post the URL to your document here. The `RESULTS.txt` file will give us technical details that are required to provide more than a wild guess of an answer.